# Configure Spring-Boot-1.4.3 With Elastic Search 6.1.1

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch

Error:

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/action/count/CountRequestBuilder

I am using below configurations to generate my transport client.

```
@Bean
public Client client() throws Exception {
    System.setProperty("es.set.netty.runtime.available.processors", "false");
    Settings esSettings = Settings.builder()
            .put("cluster.name", EsClusterName)
            .build();
    TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(esSettings);
    if (hosts != null && !hosts.isEmpty()) {
        for (ElasticHost elasticHosts2 : hosts) {
            logger.info(String.format("Adding Elastic Cluster, Host - %s : %s", elasticHosts2.getHost(),
                    elasticHosts2.getPort()));
            final InetAddress elasticHost = InetAddress.getByName(elasticHosts2.getHost());
            client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(elasticHost, elasticHosts2.getPort()));
        }
    } else {
        client.addTransportAddress(new TransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(EsHost), EsPort));
    }
    return client;
}
```

Could someone please suggest whether is it compatible with spring boot 1.4.3 with elastic-6.1.1.

if yes then should i miss anything...or is there any other way to use either low level rest client or expose elastic template.

Answer (score 2):

The following table shows the Elasticsearch versions that are used by Spring Data release trains and version of Spring Data Elasticsearch included in that, as well as the Spring Boot versions referring to that particular Spring Data release train:
[![]Various versions of elastic which are supported by Spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrobf.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mrobf.png)

Also, refer to this elasticsearch GitHub repository for dependencies and plugins with appropriate documentation.